# Why does python not optimize memory references to objects?

Tags: python-3.x

In python, given the following:

```
l=["A"]
s="A"
t=("A")
```

why is that id(l[0]) not the same as id(s[0]) or id(t[0]). I was expecting the list element at index 0 to optimize and reference the same object as at s[0] and at t[0]

Answer (score 0):

They should be the same. In Python 3.3,

```
>>> l=["A"]; s="A"; t=("A")
>>> id(l[0]) == id(s[0]) == id(t[0])
True
```

Can you check this on your version?

Comment: I am using version 3.2. id(s[0]) is same as id(t[0]) but id(l[0]) is different.

Comment: Huh, interesting.  Must be a bug that was patched in more recent versions.  Though I can't comment on why this is.